# Java empty stack exception - JD Edwards BI Publisher subtemplate

Tags: bi-publisher, jdedwards

I have been trying to conditionally import logos onto my main template. The logos are stored in an external rtf file

```
<?template:Logo06000?>
  Some logo here
<?end template?>
```

In my main template I am importing the logo using

```
<?import: file:///C:/Users/Documents/BIP Templates/R03B505 AR Invoice/BIP 
Templates/logos.rtf ?>
<?call: Logo06000?>
```

However every time I try to preview the report in the main template I am getting this error.

```
oracle.xdo.XDOException: java.util.EmptyStackException
    at oracle.xdo.template.fo.util.FOUtility.generateFO(FOUtility.java:1300)
    at oracle.xdo.template.fo.util.FOUtility.generateFO(FOUtility.java:308)
    at oracle.xdo.template.FOProcessor.createFO(FOProcessor.java:2110)
    at oracle.xdo.template.FOProcessor.generate(FOProcessor.java:1213)
    at RTF2PDF2.runRTFto(RTF2PDF2.java:484)
    at RTF2PDF2.runXDO(RTF2PDF2.java:343)
    at RTF2PDF2.main(RTF2PDF2.java:235)
Caused by: java.util.EmptyStackException
    at oracle.xdo11g.xslt.XSLProcessor.reportException
```

I have tried everything but  I do not know why this error is being thrown? Do I need to install or add any config files on my local machine? Any help or suggestion on how to fix this would be helpful.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Check this document from Oracle

https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?_afrLoop=403370819287855&id=2247221.1&_afrWindowMode=0&_adf.ctrl-state=j6yky0e1l_4

1. Go to the installed location of BIP Desktop:

For example, C:\Program Files(x86)\Oracle\BI Publisher\BI Publisher Desktop\Template Builder

2. Open the configuration file: xdo.cfg
3. Add the below property to make it work

false